# workflow rehosted designer 4.0 error after installing .Net 4.5

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, .net-4.5

After installing .Net 4.5, my rehosted workflow designer is suddenly giving me errors at runtime :

- the project is still targeted at 4.0 (and it should remain that way)
- it compiles without errors
- when I try to load an existing XAML, an exception occurs.

  _workflowDesigner.Text = xaml;

  _workflowDesigner.Load();

**exception on Load method:**
can not convert an object of type System.Windows.Input.CommandBinding to System.Activities.Presentation.View.DesignerView

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks like maybe a versioning issue? Or resource localization bug. Since you mention Visual Studio 2012 it sounds like maybe it comes from having a combination of .Net 4.5 and .Net Client Profile 4.0 DEU.

Note that installing VS 2012 will always install .Net 4.5.

It seems like there is a .Net 4.5 DEU Language pack. I am guessing that may have better compatibility with .Net 4.5. Could you try uninstalling the Framework 4 one, and installing this one instead? http://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=30667

Reference : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/wfprerelease/thread/19bdb5c5-ee04-48b8-bd8b-5a45d0fc2de6

Comment: Indeed, after uninstalling (in my case dutch) 4.0 language packs and installing 4.5 language packs, it works again.. THX, strange that those language packs are not updated automatically by .NET 4.5 installer

Comment: Uninstalled all 4.0 language packs and that worked. Those language packs was installed automatically because my setup had a prerequisite on .net 4.0 and I have **4.5** installed on my machine